# Simple Horizontal Button / Menu Bar Dreamweaver

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I'm just starting out with HTML and Dreamweaver. Basicly, I'm trying to create a simple, horizontal menu bar with mouseover and "browser resize" so the bar will be stretched to span the browser window etc.

Maybe someone could recommend a good tutorial for getting started with these beginner tasks.

I stuck a picture below so you know what I mean by "horizontal".

[image: picture]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you in the ballpark. You may need to tweak it a bit to your liking. But the underlying concept is there.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">

#navbar {
width:100%;
height:40px;
background-color:#000;
}

#navbar ul {
width:80%;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

#navbar ul li {
float:left;
color:#CC0000;
padding:0 20px 0 20px;
border-right:1px solid #FFF;
border-left:1px solid #FFF;
height:40px;
list-style:none;
display:block;
line-height:40px;
text-align:center;
cursor:pointer;
}

#navbar ul li:hover {
background-color:#CCC;
}

</style>
    <div id="navbar">

        <ul>
            <li>Link 1</li>
            <li>Link 2</li>
            <li>Link 3</li>
            <li>Link 4</li>
            <li>Link 5</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**FIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/xbf5xq3n/1/

Answer (score 1):

You should do it with Un-ordered list like shown below.

```
<ul class=".mynavul">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="serviceappointment.html">Service appointment</a></li>
        <li><a href="pools&amp;spas.html">Pools &amp; spas</a></li>
        <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html" class="active">Contact us</a></li>
        <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>


      </ul>
```

and the CSS should be as shown below so it displays horizontally

```
/* for the Ul */

ul.mynavul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
        display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}




/* for the Li */ 

ul .mynavul li {
    float: left;
    width: 141px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
        display: block;
    margin-top: 19px;
    color: #D8DCD8;
    font-size: 14px;
}


/* for the Links */ 

ul .mynavul li a {
    color: #CCC;

}


/* for the Links Hover */ 

ul .mynavul li a:hover {
    color: #CCC;

}



/* Adjust the Colors, Width, and Height  as needed */
```